# Is it possible to use a php file in android studio?

Tags: android

Me and my group are working on a school final project. We're creating an android application and we divided tasks. One of my group mates was in charge of creating the algorithm for our app but he coded it with PHP and now we're close to our dead line. I don't think there's still time to convert the PHP code to java since it has 2000 lines. Is it possible to use the algorithm written in PHP and integrate it into our android app or are we screwed?

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use WebView to access the php from android

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.web);//R.id.web from your layout file
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way, make a restful request to the php code.Your api endpoints, are simply use android webview system to display the site.
I recommend using this library.https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android

Very slick and allows easy customization.

Comment: also your question was not structured in a proper manner.http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274